# Struggling with a DAX Measure and Need Assistance

Tags: subquery, dax, tableau-api, calculated-field

I am trying to recreate this Tableau LOD calculation in Power BI using DAX.  The data is sourced from a single table and there will be slicers applied to the PBI report page, as well as potentially filters applied to the report sheet.

sum({fixed [Work Site Group],[Work Facility],[Work Costcenter],[Pay End Date]: avg([Payperiod Adc])})

Here is one failed attempt.
CALCULATE (
AVERAGE ( NursingOps_Hospital_Analysis[payperiod_adc] ),
ALLEXCEPT (
NursingOps_Hospital_Analysis,
NursingOps_Hospital_Analysis[work_site_group],
NursingOps_Hospital_Analysis[work_facility],
NursingOps_Hospital_Analysis[work_costcenter],
NursingOps_Hospital_Analysis[pay_end_date]
)
)

I have also experimented with variations of the "summarize" functions in DAX, but to no avail.